# refactoring combinelatest for rxjs

Tags: angular, rxjs, rxjs6

I'm trying to refactor my code from rxjs 5.x to rxjs 6 and Angular 6. I had a code that essentially triggers a search:

```
  startAt = new Subject();
  endAt = new Subject();

  startobs = this.startAt.asObservable();
  endobs = this.endAt.asObservable();

  constructor() {}

  ngOnInit(){

    var that = this;

    Observable.combineLatest(this.startobs, this.endobs)
    .subscribe((value) => {
      this.acctServ.searchAccounts(value[0], value[1])
      .subscribe((accounts) => {
console.log("accounts : ", accounts);
          });


      })


    });
  }
```

In order to refactor this I did the following:

```
startAt = new Subject();
  endAt = new Subject();

  startobs = this.startAt.asObservable();
  endobs = this.endAt.asObservable();

  constructor() { 

  }//End of Constructor

  ngOnInit() {

    Observable.create().pipe(combineLatest(this.startobs, this.endobs))
    .subscribe((value) => {
      console.log("Search Box Obersable : ", value);

      this.acctServ.searchAccounts(value[0], value[1])
      .subscribe((accounts) => {

        console.log("accounts : ", accounts);
          });


      })


    });

  }//End of ngOnInit
```

However, this doesn't seem to have helped and the search is no longer being triggered. I was wondering how to actually refactor this code to work with rxjs 6 ?

Comment: Just replace `Observable.combineLatest` by `combineLatest` in your original code, and import `combineLatest` from `rxjs`. https://rxjs-dev.firebaseapp.com/api/index/function/combineLatest. You should also learn about the switchMap operator instead of subscribing inside a subscribe.

Comment: Thank you, I thought I was generating the observable via Observable. This makes sense.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're using `combineLatest` operator imported from `"rxjs/operators"` while you should be using `combineLatest` creation method imported from `"rxjs"`:

What you have now `Observable.create().pipe(combineLatest(this.startobs, this.endobs))` is the same as the following:

```
import { combineLatest } from 'rxjs';

combineLatest(Observable.create(), this.startobs, this.endobs)
  ...
```

This will never emit anything because `combineLatest` requires all source Observables to emit at least one value. However `Observable.create()` doesn't emit anything by itself so  `combineLatest` doesn't emit either.

Instead you should be using just the following:

```
import { combineLatest } from 'rxjs';

combineLatest(this.startobs, this.endobs)
  ...
```